# Pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

after googling my specific inquiry online, I haven't found much luck. Basically what I'm trying to do is take a excel file what has lots of columns. Now I'm only interested in some of these columns to be included in a pivot table. Is there a way to automatically create a pivot table, via a script of some sort which will occupy the desired columns in a pivot table that I want to take from the original excel file?

Thank you

Comment: 1) you can make a PivotTable on all the columns, then just show the columns you want 2) you can make a new sheet with only the columns for the PivotTable and based the PT on that sheet

Comment: I would like the functionality of someone else who extracts this data to be able to automatically create a pivot table. This would be easy for them and for others who cannot use excel well. Basically it is for the ease of use of others

Comment: so, then you'll need to use a listbox or userform to allow people to select the columns they want to see and base your code off that

Comment: Would I do that using VBA? Or what is the general approach

Comment: The three columns that we want to appear are constant. I don't think there is a need for UI other than the user perhaps clicking a script which would create the pivot table itself

Comment: What would help is if you provided some code, and we could probably tweak it from there with you.  Start the macro recorder in Excel, then create your pivot table and format/customize it as you wish.  Edit your post with the VBA that was generated from the macro recorder.

Comment: In seeing your comment you would like the functionality of someone else to create the pivot, if you create a macro from the VBA Recorder you could then add an Active X Button that will run the macro from the onclick() event - that way anyone who can click the button will then be able to create the pivot table.

Comment: Hi, I mainly specialize with backend technologies, so I do not know how to use VBA, but since this is a feature my workplace needs to utilize I am willing to learn. I just wanted to figure out what exactly I would need to learn in order for this to be possible. Right Now I have an excel file which has the names of employees,hours, etc etc. I want to make it very easy; easy as a click as you suggest perhaps, for someone in hr to take the original excel file and output it into a pivot table which has headers saying which employee they are, the hours worked and the date.

Comment: Could you loo kat my new question ive added some code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this for real is to set your file up to make the call to the database and specify that the destination is a pivot table.

How this is done depends greatly on what your data source is.  But the functionality to do this is built in to the program without having to use VB at all.

Comment: I see. So I would need to perhaps use some PHP to read the excel file to MySQL, and then make a table based off that info?

Comment: Well, no...  You connect Excel directly to the database server.  You write your SQL code right there.  If you must use PHP, then use that to get the data dump, and use that dump as your data source.

Comment: I see. I've never done any coding or connecting using Excel itself, so it looks like I'm going to have to research a bit on that.

Comment: in the DATA tab in the ribbon, over on the left, there are 5 methods for this.  Once your establish one of those methods, and you have your data source working, the last step is "how do you want this placed in Excel"  Choose it as a pivot table.

Comment: I need this to be made so that HR can easily just do something say, at the click of a button or just run a script and the original spreadsheet that they get will be converted into a pivot table. Is doing what you suggest still the best approach?

Comment: Yes.   You are essentially making a refreshable sheet.   And if you create a macro for it,  you can make a button to run the update.

Comment: I see. How do I get started? I am not too experienced with excel?

Comment: I wouldn't normally provide a link for this.  but it's just too much to write in a comment. Take a look at this:  https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_guide_to_importing  Even if you don't do that exact method, it shows you how to get moving.

Comment: is MySQL really needed? Given someone has the spreadsheet can't I just create a macro of some sort to create pivot table on click?

Comment: Great I've got VBA up and running, now I just need to look at some code that will give me what I need

Comment: Could you look at my new question? I've added some code